# How does this table building code work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, methods, higher-order-functions

These functions are from http://eloquentjavascript.net/. It is not my code, but since it is in a free textbook, I think it should be okay for educational purposes, esp. when anyone can just go to the website and get it.

---

**The full code is used for building a table; this is the first part. Maybe it is that there are so many functions within functions that it is confusing me?**

```
function rowHeights(rows) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
      return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
    }, 0);
  });
}

function colWidths(rows) {
  return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
      return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

Then they go on with the actual drawing of a table; I might understand this if I understand the first part:

```
function drawTable(rows) {
  var heights = rowHeights(rows);
  var widths = colWidths(rows);

  function drawLine(blocks, lineNo) {
    return blocks.map(function(block) {
      return block[lineNo];
    }).join(" ");
  }

  function drawRow(row, rowNum) {
    var blocks = row.map(function(cell, colNum) {
      return cell.draw(widths[colNum], heights[rowNum]);
    });
    return blocks[0].map(function(_, lineNo) {
      return drawLine(blocks, lineNo);
    }).join("\n");
  }

  return rows.map(drawRow).join("\n");
}
```

I don't think I need an answer on the second part; if I do after understanding the first part, I will post a second question.

They even have more code later; if it is helpful, I could also copy that to here, too, if it is asked for in the comments.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowHeights` returns an array containing the height of each row of the table. For each row, it gets its height by getting the maximum height of each cell in the row.

To understand it, work from the inside out:

```
function(max, cell) {
    return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
}
```

Given a cell and a previous maximum height, this computes the new height as the maximum of this cell's `minHeight()` and the previous maximum.

```
return row.reduce(ABOVE FUNCTION, 0);
```

This reduces a row (an array of cells), using the above function, to get the maximum height of all the cells in the row.

Then:

```
return rows.map(PREVIOUS FUNCTION);
```

runs the reduction function over every row, returning an array of all the maximum heights.

`colWidths` does the same thing by column, getting the width of each column by getting the maximum with of each cell in that column.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar! Your explanation is helpful. Is it possible that I could get a step-by-step, line-by-line answer? If not, that is perfectly okay, but it would really help me understand.:) If so, you would not have to explain methods like reduce or map, because I know those, just how the parts of the puzzle fit together. I do understand, however, if this is too much to ask for. Thanks again for an answer! :) !!

Comment: If you understand what `reduce` and `map` do, then you should be able to work out what the whole thing does. Just work from the inside out.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I guess that I was trying to work the code out from the outside in.

Comment: Just in case someone has the same problem: 
You can actually use the array.map method to simulate a for loop, that's why the callback has no value ("_") and the current index is passed on.

I don't get though what the second part does really. Is this programming style (map instead of for and so many returns) something other people find easy to read?

Comment: It uses `map` so that it can return an array and then call `.join()` on them. So it's equivalent to a `for` loop that uses `temparray.push()` and then afterward returns `temparay.join()`. I guess the original programmer really likes the functional style of programming.